# IE 8, 9, 10 - YouTube iFrame Error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

YouTube iFrame Players created using the iFrame API are now broken in  IE 8, 9, 10 - though none of the code has changed on my side. It also seems that the issue exists with other embeds.

This YouTube demo, for example, doesn't work in IE:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

The video plays for a few seconds and then switches to HD and then errors out.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today.  When you listen for the onStateChange event, the event.target YouTube player dispatched to this event used to have an numeric .id for each embed on the page, and that ID seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

I believe this to be an issue on Google's side...

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same error ... did you manage to fix or work around this? Or is this really something google should fix and all we can do is wait?

Comment: I did not resolve this issue and I no longer have an interest in doing so (new job)... I had planned on replacing our video player with VideoJS or MediaElement, which both support YouTube and work fine in IE.